# How to load Markdown files using an AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filesystems, markdown

I'm trying to build a blog using Angular.

I have a controller and its associated view.  I also have an assets folder with a number of markdown pages.  I'll have a directive in the view whose contents will be filled with a certain markdown file's contents.

What I would like to do is have a simple function in my controller which loads the contents of one of the markdown files into the controller, then that can populate the directive.

Where I am stuck is how do I load one file (I'm assuming I'll know its name and path), into my controller?  Do I have to use something like Browserify so I can can use the 'fs' node module, or is there a simpler way to access the file system?

Comment: And now you just add your code? One doesn't just access the file system using JS.

Answer (score 1):

Files on the filesystem can not be accessed using JS, you would need to publish the markdown pages to a webserver, or make a service on your backend that returns the content of the file.

Either way, the markdown will need to present on the server.